# Google cloud storage - Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.list access to project XXXXXXXXXX

Tags: swift, google-cloud-storage

I am using swift to make an API call to my google cloud buckets.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=<project id>")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Data is empty")
        return
    }

    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
}

task.resume()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

unfortunately, this is what is got:

```
{
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = global;
                location = Authorization;
                locationType = header;
                message = "Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.list access to project <project id>.";
                reason = required;
            }
        );
        message = "Anonymous users does not have storage.buckets.list access to project <project id>.";
    };
}
```

google cloud documentation is very confusing. I don't know how to specify user in this case. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

Listing buckets requires your request to be authorized as a user or service account with `storage.buckets.list` permssion. This is typically an account with the "Owner", "Editor", "Viewer" or "storage.admin" role on the project.

The first thing to decide is whether you want to authorize as a user or a service account. Choose User authorization if this swift application is going to be accessing projects belonging to an end user. Chose service account auth if need to list buckets in your application's own project.

If you choose service account, you must create a sevice account and generate credentials for it (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts)) and then use that within your app to generate a JWT that you pass in an Authorization header during your API call (see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests)).

If you choose authenticating on behalf of your end users, your application must do the "OAuth 2.0 Three legged flow" where your app sends your user to Google with a request for a token, Google then gives the user a authentication dialog and choice to grant access to your application, and if they say yes redirects them back with a refresh token. Your app then can use the refresh token along with API calls (or better, uses the refresh token to get a short lived access token to send). How you do this depends on the type of application, see [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios) for details.